Canonical angle between two subspaces
I try to understand the concept of canonical angles / principal angles based on equations (6)-(8) from the paper Numerical methods for computing angles between linear subspaces and equations (1.1)-(1.2) from the paper Principal Angles between Subspaces in an A-Based Scalar Product: Algorithms and Perturbation Estimates and subseequently to apply it to my scenario involving a semi-unitary and a unitary matrix.
I understand that for a semi-unitary matrix $Q_{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{M \times p}$ (with $M>p$ and $Q_{A}^{H}Q_{A} = I$ but $Q_{A}Q_{A}^{H} \neq I$) and a unitary matrix $Q_{B}\in\mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$ (with $Q_{B}Q_{B}^{H}=Q_{B}^{H}Q_{B}=I$) I first have to consider the product (resulting in another semi-unitary matrix)
\begin{equation}
M = Q_{A}^{H}Q_{B} \in\mathbb{C}^{p \times M}
\end{equation}
and then calculate the $\arccos$ from the obtained singular values of the unitary matrix  $M$, i.e. $\arccos(\sigma(M))$. That $M$ is semi-unitary can be easily seen from
\begin{align}
MM^{H} &=  Q_{A}^{H}Q_{B}Q_{B}^{H}Q_{A} = Q_{A}^{H}IQ_{A} = Q_{A}^{H}Q_{A} = I\\
M^{H}M &= Q_{B}^{H}Q_{A}Q_{A}^{H}Q_{B} \neq  I \quad\text{since } Q_{A}Q_{A}^{H}\neq I
\end{align}
I am missing the last step now: what general conclusions can be said about singular values of semi-unitary matrices? I have the feeling that for such semi-unitary matrices one can show that all singular values are in the range $[0,1]$ in order to be able to evaluate the $\arccos$ such that only angles in the range $[0,\pi/2]$ come out. Unfortunately I cannot find any statements regarding SVDs of semi-orthogonal or semi-unitary matrices. Can you help me with this? Thank you
Edit no.1: I checked with MATLAB the following example with $p_{A} = p_{B}$
M  = 4;

x = randn(M,1)+1i.*randn(M,1);
A = x*x';
A = orth(A)

x = randn(M,1)+1i.*randn(M,1);
B = x*x';
B = orth(B)

subspace(A,B)

As expected, for these two rank-1 matrices, the largest angle (ouput of subspace.m) is of course unequal to zero, confirming my intuitiont that I didn't fully get the math.
Edit no.2: thanks to the comment of @Vladimir Lysikov for noting that a non square matrix cannot be unitary but ony semi-unitary, i.e. if  $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{M \times p}$ with $M>p$ then $Q^{H}Q=I$ but $QQ^{H}\neq I$.

$M$ is not in general unitary. If $p < M$, then for a unitary $M \times p$ matrix $U$ we have $U^H U = I$, but not $UU^H = I$, but you use the second equality in your derivation.
Look for example at the extreme case $p_A = p_B = 1$, so that $Q_A$ and $Q_B$ are just columns, and $Q_A^H Q_B$ is exactly the inner product of these columns.

Thank you for the reminder that not necessarily $U^H U = I$ as well as $UU^H = I$ hold!

Regarding my statement "I have the feeling that for such semi-unitary matrices one can show that all singular values are in the range $[0,1]$" The proof can be found in Ch. 6.4.3 in Golub and Van Loan, 4th ed,


a related thread is here
